# WPF catch Click on a grid and all of his children labels, textboxs, etc.

Tags: c#, wpf

Lets say I have a xaml file, a window, why not. in this xaml I have a **grid** with multiple labels, textBoxs, comboBoxs, lists... You see the patern. At a certain point (where X == true for say) I want to be able to *catch* a click inside the grid *and everything in it.*

I want to be still able to do what this click was going to do so a full-filled Rect over the grid is not the answer I'm looking for. The action of the click would be to put X back to false. nothing much.

Is there an easy way to manage a click on a grid and everything inside it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to use an event that is common to all of the controls. Probably the best one for this scenario is the [`UIElement.PreviewMouseDown` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try this:

```
<StackPanel UIElement.PreviewMouseDown="StackPanel_PreviewMouseDown">
    <Label Content="I'm a Label" />
    <Button Content="I'm a Button" />
    <CheckBox Content="I'm a CheckBox" />
</StackPanel>
```

You need to use one of the `Preview...` events so that you can catch it before the `Button`s consume it... the `UIElement.MouseDown` event wouldn't work with `Button`s for that very reason. However, you can use the othwer `Preview...` methods, like the `UIElement.PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown` event, for example.

Comment: This is perfect. And even instructionnal! you are amazing. :D

Comment: I used PreviewMouseDown from Properties panel; that works very good.

Answer (score 3):

Can you give your sample code?

From my understanding,you can use this,it will capture all your click inside grid.

**.xaml**

```
<Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
<Label MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" />
<Button MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"/>
<Button MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"/>
</Grid>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
private Grid_MouseDown(object sender,MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(X==true)
    {
      //doSomething
    }
    else
    {
     //do SomethingElse
    }
}
```

edit: How about this?

Comment: it does capture all clicks inside grid, but not the clicks on the labels, the buttons, etc. which doesn't fill my needs.

Comment: Just add a background: `<Grid Background="Transparent"` and you catch a click in the "empty" space, too.